# How to add an event handler on .clone element

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a table row, which is clone from the parent..

Here is the code:

```
$(this).closest("tr").clone(true).off().attr("class", "newclass").appendTo("#comparelist");
```

and I also add this code:

```
  $(".newclass").hover(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
```

The table row has been clone successfully, but it can't trigger the hover function..

Does anyone know why this is happen?

Thank You..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use delegated event handlers

```
$("#comparelist").on({
   mouseenter : function () {
       alert("mouse entered");
   },
   mouseleave : function () {
       alert("mouse left");
   }
}, ".newclass");
```

and remove `off()`

```
var clone = $(this).closest("tr").clone(true);

clone.attr("class", "newclass");
clone.appendTo("#comparelist");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $(document).on('hover', '.newclass', function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to delegate the event on that element, because that was created dynamically.
So you can use `live`, `deligate` or `on` event binding methods. I recommend to use `on` method.

Here is the example.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".newclass", function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Good Luck!